# How to change PyCharm code editor background color?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to change the background color for the PyCharm source code editor. How can I do that?

I am running it under Ubuntu.

Comment: Here is a pretty good description: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Comment: I am sorry, but I could not find the specific setting to change the background color of the editor, neither in the settings dialogue nor in the documentation linked above.

Comment: Editor > Colors & Fonts > General:    Expand `Text`,  select `Default text`, you'll find `Backgroud` color setting on the right.

Comment: So good a question to get back healthy default light theme instead of ever night.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Providing @Guoliang's helpful comment as a formal answer, as the accepted answer does not answer the question:

Go to `Settings` > `Editor` > `Colors & Fonts` > `General`

On the right side, expand `Text` and select `Default text`

Modify `Background` as desired.

Answer (score 26):

In PyCharm 2017/2018/2019+ it is:

`Settings` > `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `General`

And then simply expand ***Text***, choose ***Default text*** and set the background color on the right.

[image: PyCharm]

Another tip on the topic: if you want the selected background color to also be used in all tree views(Project, Structure, etc.) you can use the [Color IDE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7055-color-ide) plugin.

And if you want ta completely black IDE (great for OLED-displays), instead of Darcula-gray, have a look at the new high contrast theme included in 2018.3:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/10/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-high-contrast-theme-and-more-accessibility-improvements/

Comment: I keep having to look this up, can never find the setting in the UI.

Comment: @Dominik Just use search field, otherwise it's mostly tricky.

Answer (score 6):

A shortcut to bring up the style menu is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (that's the backtick key usually under <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

It brings up the Switch menu, with options for Color Scheme and Look and Feel. 
[image: Switch menus]

The Color Scheme setting controls the colors of the main code editor pane. The Look and Feel setting controls the color for the entire interface (including the code editor if the Color Scheme is Default).

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme
Under Schemes, select **Dracula** (it's a dark background). One can select others as well based on your likings.

Comment: There were far too many ways to configure individual settings above but switch to a theme was the better way to go.   Thanks for this.  Everything was black when I started to look at it.  The default theme was just what I needed.