# How to change the backgroundcolor of pycharm？

Tags: pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppfY2.png)

Anyone tells me?Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change PyCharm code editor background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239686/how-to-change-pycharm-code-editor-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

you can find here ,
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51945983

Go to `Settings` > `Editor` > `Colors & Fonts` > `General`

On the right side, expand `Text` and select `Default text`

Modify `Background` as desired