# How to make visual code terminal and editor look like pycharm

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a django app and I really like developing with PyCharm but it's way too heavy so I am switching to Visual Code.

However, I would like not to lose some of the "look and feel" of pycharm when it comes to the terminal and code so I am trying to turn these (terminal and editor of VisualCode)

[image]
[image]

Into these (terminal and editor of PyCharm)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change PyCharm code editor background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239686/how-to-change-pycharm-code-editor-background-color)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is to change to look and feel of the application.
On your visual studio code, Open the extensions tab then search "Darcula PyCharm Theme" Click on install. You will achieve what you want.

Comment: and for pycharm light theme(intelliJ Light) - use "Intellij IDEA light theme" package

Comment: @YardenCohen that does not give you Pycharm's default font styling.

Comment: yeah @AnshulTiwari its not perfect either.. I'm now using **Laravel PyCharm Theme**, which is also not 100% but at least give you colors for 'self' and stuffs like that, that a lot of others are missing